# Why will my HTML content display but not my PHP?

Tags: php, atom-editor

I am learning PHP for a login system on my website. After following numerous online tutorials, i decided to use atom, having installed both the ide-php package on atom  and the actual PHP files. To test this i wrote a (very) simple program with a little HTML and some PHP. It's called new.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <body class="page_bg">
    Some PHP: <?php echo 'Hello'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when i run it in the html-previewer (another atom package) only the HTML came out - `Some PHP:`. When I checked the console, there was no error. Next I tried opening it with internet explorer. The window closed as soon as it was opened. Why is this happening?

Comment: You viewed the source or just the browser rendering? I'd guess `html-previewer` is bypassing the PHP processor.

Comment: I looked at the source also, and the php was in a comment. I think you are right, it is bypassing it, but how can i fix the problem?

Comment: Use wamp to "host" the website and be able to run PHP. Then you just navigate to 127.0.0.1/mywebsite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [`php-server`](https://atom.io/packages/php-server), it includes a development server that lets you run your PHP code from within Atom.

Comment: I have installed it, how should i run it?

Comment: Then instructions are all visible on the page I linked to, even in the screenshot

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but  I get this error on Chrome: localhost refused to connect.

Comment: It works fine for me out of the box. In the package settings you can specify a different hostname and port, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the Atom packages site, located [here](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=php) and search for the 'language php' package and install that in your current version of Atom. The ide-php package does not contain the php language package. Install that package and then try your code again.